# Custom XSLT with instance validation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I have a map that uses a custom XSLT. When running the "Test Map" within VS I get the expected outcome, even on my "fail" instance that does not comply with my destination schema. But when deployed to my BizTalk Server the "fail" instance does not fail.

So the question is, when using a custom XSLT is the instance not validated against the source and destination schemas provided in the XSLT?

If not, what is applied on a map when using the visual mapper since this seems to work?

Answer (score 1):

Schema validation never happens by default during runtime processing within BizTalk, for performance reasons.

You observed failed instances at design-time because you had the "check output instance validation" property set in Visual Studio. This behavior does not exist at runtime because, by then, your documents should have been validated during unit and integration testing.

If you need runtime validation, you probably need to execute a validating XmlReceive Pipeline downstream, perhaps in the subscribing orchestra, for instance.